# How to find nested values in fire-base database where ids are not known?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a chat application with a firebase as my backend. The issue is that I have created two tables in the firebase database one to store users and others for messages.
My table is as follows...

```
{
  "chat-group" : {
    "a0d4086c-66f7-4437-a23f-4b8e07da9bb8" : {
      "userId1" : "cdc0f59c-66b2-4bac-abe1-fe89a0e29a28",
      "userId2" : "382a321d-8bcd-4b62-bb4e-25b7c1df4ca2"
    },
    "b9afcd88-0b6a-4e77-8dd7-ea3fc17962b9" : {
      "userId1" : "cdc0f59c-66b2-4bac-abe1-fe89a0e29a28",
      "userId2" : "cb754c6b-1702-47dd-a3b8-b34e970ea9a2"
    }
  },
  "messages" : {
    "a0d4086c-66f7-4437-a23f-4b8e07da9bb8" : {
      "-LtT1kMDQrrkSbIDscnz" : {
        "name" : "Parth Shrivastav",
        "text" : "hello",
        "timestamp" : 1573535811230
      }
    },
    "b9afcd88-0b6a-4e77-8dd7-ea3fc17962b9" : {
      "-LtT1xclHzrnY_xSWrMJ" : {
        "name" : "Parth Shrivastav",
        "text" : "",
        "timestamp" : 1573535865601
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to relate the chat id under the users table with the chat id under the messages and retrieve the message under the auto-generated id of that chat Id.

```
database().ref('messages/b9afcd88-0b6a-4e77-8dd7-ea3fc17962b9)
        this.ref
            .limitToLast(20)
            .on('child_added', snapshot =>
            snapshot.forEach(msgdata => {
              console.log(msgdata)
```

By using forEach for the data the database seems to behave static and does not update when any new message seems to be available in data. I need to refresh the screen for any new data.

Comment: 1) Please replace the schematic database representation with the actual JSON (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). 2) Can you reproduce the problem with a hard-coded value for `$chatID`? If so, please edit your question to only include that hard-coded value. That would also exclude the `/users` node from the potential problem.

Comment: Sure, I have edited the question as you mentioned

Comment: The code snippet in your question is invalid right now. Please make sure that the [code actually runs, is standalone (meaning we can run it just like you give it too, and reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're listening for `child_added` events, the Firebase client will call your code for each message under `messages/b9afcd88-0b6a-4e77-8dd7-ea3fc17962b9`. This means you don't need to loop over the children `snapshot` in the code, and can just get the message's properties straight from the `snapshot`.

```
.on('child_added', snapshot =>
  console.log(snapshot.val());
}
```